# How to display HashSet<SortedSet<string>> collection in richTextBox?

Tags: c#, hashset

I have HashSet> collection. I want to display content of this HashSet in richTextBox ? How to convert this HashSet to right type ?

Comment: What GUI framework are you using? E.g. `WindowsForms`, `WPF`?

Comment: I'm using WindowsForms,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this instead:

```
foreach (SortedSet<string> set in youHashSet)
{
    richTextBox.Text = string.Join("", set.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: @abecadlo as long as your Hashset is already a string, if you need to convert future objects see my suggestion below

Comment: @abecadlo actually if it's already a string  foreach(string mystring in youHastSet) will work

Comment: @Mike slingzor's suggestion works well :) Anyway thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @abecadlo i don't disagree, but remember a Hashset is just a collection, so sometimes you need to cast the object property to string.  It's helpful if you create a custom class that contains multiple properties

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
richTextBox.Text = string.Join("", yourSet.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

Well a little bit of more information would have helped.  It's hard to say without seeing your code.  But these are your basic steps

after you build your Hashset
then for a for or foreach loop on it
and then ToString the object if it's not a Hashset

```
string helloWorld = string.empty;
foreach(<whateverobject> myobject in Hashset<whateverobject> myHashsetList)
{
 helloWorld = helloWorld = myobject.ToString();
}
richTextBox.Text = helloWorld;
```

If you delimit it or whatever that's up to you